# Getting a none type error while iterating a dictionary?

Tags: python

Code:-

```
def displayHand(hand):
    for letter in hand.keys():
       for j in range(hand[letter]):
         print letter,              # print all on the same line
    print                               # print an empty line

hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}

print displayHand(hand)
```

Output:-

```
a i m l l q u
None
```

Req Output:-

```
a i m l l q u
```

Kindly give a logical solution.

Comment: Did you `print displayHand(hand)` anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not `return` anything thus when you print the result of the function it prints `None`

```
displayHand(hand) # execute the function without printing the result, in this case None
```

Answer (score 3):

`displayHand` returns nothing. Just remove the `print` of the end of your code and it will work.

```
def displayHand(hand):
    for letter in hand.keys():
       for j in range(hand[letter]):
         print letter,              # print all on the same line
    print                               # print an empty line

hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}

displayHand(hand)
```

Output:

```
a i m l l q u
```

Answer (score 1):

`displayHand()` function does not return anything, hence when you do -

```
print displayHand(hand)
```

This actually prints `None` , since `displayHand()` did not return anything. Just call it as normal without the `print` -

```
displayHand(hand)
```